# Does it matter who I challenge?

Tags: rhythm-heaven-megamix

I know it is cheaper to do the harder gate challenges, but is there any other differences other than cost and difficulty? Does the challenge I choose at the gate affect the game in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

As far as beating the story goes, I haven't noticed anything being affected by which guard you challenge, so you should just make your choice based on how many coins you have and what difficulty level you're comfortable with.

However, you need to go back and beat all three guards' challenges in order to unlock endless mode for that gate's minigame (found in the gallery).